# How can I set docker to use an existing disk image in another location?

Tags: docker, docker-desktop

I had previously set my disk image location using Docker Desktop, but since Docker updated to the latest version it now points to another `Docker.raw` file in the old default location.

How can I set Docker to use the `docker.raw` in the path I had before the update?

In the UI there are only two options. `Move disk folder` and `Reveal in Finder`.

I do not want to move the new disk image to the old path. I want to use the disk image that is already in there.

Comment: What is this disk image location ? I haven't encountered it yet.